# Where do I find the Eclipse JavaServer Faces config editor palette?

Tags: eclipse, editor, palette

While running through the cheat sheet "create a navigation rule" for the [Eclipse JavaServer Faces tooling](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_javaserver_faces_tooling_user_guide/topic/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/wpe/eclipse_jsf_user_wpe_getting_started.html) it says "select the page control from the palette and ...". But where's this "palette"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, in [Ganymede](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) at least, on the right-hand border of the JavaServer Faces configuration editor tab there is a subtle left arrow head. clicking that shows palette.

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anyone is struggling now to find it I have added a screenshot showing exactly where it is:

[palette image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o63WS.png)